# Не распознаются аудио с русской речью с помощью библиотеки SpeechRecognition в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

Есть код в Python:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
harvard = sr.AudioFile('/content/audio.wav')
with harvard as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
print(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

Английская речь распознается без проблем, а вот русская нет. Вместо русского текста печатается абракадабра на английском.

Comment: Нужно задать язык

Comment: r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages

Comment: Александр, спасибо, получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Александру за оперативную помощь:

```
r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU") – Александр 39 минут назад
```